# On resize the menu bar collapses, with half of the choices appearing in a line below the others

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the main menu bar of my site. However while it works fine when the browser is in full size, when I resize the menu bar collapses, with half of the choices appearing in a line below the others while I want them to remain in line even if some of them will not be visible.

What can I do using HTML and CSS in order to make the choices of the menu bar to remain in a single line even when the line is not fully visible? I 've already tried every possible position in the main menu and the linking class, adding width with percentage and pixels and adding transition and fixed position combination. Nothing helped.

```css
.main-menu {
  background-color:grey;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:xx-large;
  color: black;
}
.linking {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border:solid 2px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="main-menu">
  <a href="studenthome.html" class="linking">ΦΟΙΤΗΤΕΣ</a>
  <a href="secrethome.html" class="linking">ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΕΙΑ</a>
  <a href="publisherhome.html" class="linking">ΕΚΔΟΤΗΣ</a>
  <a href="sellerhome.html" class="linking">....</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps you. Have a look at the below code snippet.

```css
.main-menu {
  background:grey;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:xx-large;
  color: #000;
  overflow:hidden; /*to hide on collapse*/
  height:1em;
}
.linking {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 100px 0 0;
  border:2px solid red;
 
}
```

```html
<p class="main-menu">
    <a href="studenthome.html" class="linking">ΦΟΙΤΗΤΕΣ</a>
    <a href="secrethome.html" class="linking">ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΕΙΑ</a>
    <a href="publisherhome.html" class="linking">ΕΚΔΟΤΗΣ</a>
    <a href="sellerhome.html" class="linking">....</a>
</p>
```

Preview at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/8wvb4k9o/

Comment: That actually helped! However when it hide I cant reach it with scrolling right. Do you know how I could add that property too?

Comment: Do you want to show the hidden links on mouse over, so you can click them ?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be hidden but still reachable

Comment: Seems nice. However I would prefer to be reachable by scrolling so that a second line won't appear.

Comment: I managed to create a scroll by giving a class to the body with the overflow: scroll ability but the hidden choices are disappeared and when I scroll right there is only an empty page

Comment: Well now it works by adding a really large width! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Kool, the preview panel in the JSFiddle is small that might be the reason :D

Answer (score 0):

Please use below css property to do the same

```css
    .main-menu
    {
    background-color:grey;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:xx-large;
    color: black;
    max-width: 100%;    
    min-width: 1000px;
    }
    .linking
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border:solid 2px;
    border-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<p class="main-menu">
    <a href="studenthome.html" class="linking">
    ΦΟΙΤΗΤΕΣ
    </a>
    <a href="secrethome.html" class="linking">
    ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΕΙΑ
    </a>
    <a href="publisherhome.html" class="linking">
    ΕΚΔΟΤΗΣ
    </a>
    <a href="sellerhome.html" class="linking">
```

Comment: I tried it and still when I resize the browser half of the menu appears in a second line

Comment: can you try here by running code snippet ,it works fine for me

Comment: why don't try to make it responsive by using @media screen

Comment: It's because now it doesn't have enough choices in the menu bar and they can all remain in one line even when you resize. If you add one more it collapses when you resize.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.main-menu {
  background-color:grey;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:xx-large;
  color: black;
}
.main-menu .linking {
  background-color:grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border:solid 2px;
  border-color: red;
  /* added new css */
  width: 24%;        /* give width of 24% as you have 4 a-links each having 1px border */
  position: fixed;   /* set position fixed */
}
```

```html
<p class="main-menu">
  <a href="#" class="linking" style="left: 0%;">ΦΟΙΤΗΤΕΣ</a>    <!-- set left 0% as first child -->
  <a href="#" class="linking" style="left: 25%;">ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΕΙΑ</a> <!-- set left 25% as second child -->
  <a href="#" class="linking" style="left: 50%;">ΕΚΔΟΤΗΣ</a>    <!-- set left 50% as third child -->
  <a href="#" class="linking" style="left: 75%;">....</a>       <!-- set left 75% as fourth child -->
</p>
```